# How to move perforce client workspace to another location

Tags: perforce

I have created a perforce client on my local machine (eg: /usr/disk1/pclient). i need to move that synced files to another location/disk (eg: /usr/disk2/pclient), without breaking the perforce link (p4 client shouldn't be changed). how can i do that .?

Comment: What have you tried? What research have you done?

Comment: i found an answer. need to change the client root directory, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Run `p4 client` to change the client's `Root`, and then move the files in the actual workspace to match.

Use `p4 status` to double-check that you did it correctly; if the client spec doesn't match your workspace files, you'll see a bunch of files reported as needing to be added/deleted (if that's the case, don't use `reconcile` like the `status` command suggests -- instead fix the `Root` so that it actually matches the workspace and `status` reports everything as up to date).